# sql server version of mysql_fetch_assoc

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a short PHP script that interacts with a database. The script is currently written for MySQL but needs to be converted to SQL Server. I don't have experience with SQL Server and think I have done most of it correctly but in one line of the script is:

`@mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`

What is the SQL Server equivalent of this?

Do I need to edit the query line at all?

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM location WHERE dType="' . $ajax_var . '" AND oType="' . $ajax_var2 . '"';
```

Comment: While you're in there, remove the `@` and do proper error checking

Comment: Holy crap... I can smell the SQL injection from here.

Comment: @BenThul ha yes thats not the whole code... there's stuff to protect against that elsewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_assoc` returns an associative array of column names mapped to their respective value, row-by-row.  For SQL Server you want [sqlsrv_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php)

Don't be afraid of reading the docs.  ;)

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

[mssql_fetch_assoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-assoc.php) is the equivalent.  Not the recommended way to do this though.  PDO would be the correct way to go.  And whether or not the `mssql_fetch_assoc()` function exists on your server is dependent of course upon which PHP extensions you have installed.

Comment: The importance of using PDO and [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) cannot be over-stated.

Answer (score 0):

Only change the Y and the function is mssql_fetch_assoc

http://php.net/manual/es/function.mssql-fetch-assoc.php